# The MetroSE Sandboxing Question/Answer

Tags: discussion

This question is mainly for testing the [MetroSE](http://apptivate.ms/apps/28/metrose) application, specifically comments, and answers.  However, if you've ever wanted to test out your markup skillz this is a great place to do this.  Feel free to comment, answer, edit, upvote, or downvote all you want on this question, in fact I encourage it for right now as I'm testing out the application.

### But I want to play with MetroSE!

I'm waiting for official app approval and therefore you can't mess around with any 'official' versions.  However, if you have a developer account and VS 2012 (even just express) you can install MetroSE on your system and give it a whirl.

To install, navigate to this [Dropbox folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hg1juqf4tlgjcb3/dpOxM4YuBU), and open the most recent versioned folder.  Within that folder there should be a PowerShell script that, when run will install the application.  If you have any questions, ask here, or over at [Fake Programmers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116/fake-programmers).  Be sure to check the folder periodically, as I'm constantly making updates.

### I found bugs... where do I report them?

There are two way you can report MetroSE bugs

1. Email: cases@kronoskoders.fogbugz.com
2. [Online GUI](https://kronoskoders.fogbugz.com/default.asp?pg=pgPublicEdit)

Comment: This is probably a good question to try it out on: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox Fingers crossed the castles work!

Comment: How do you get to meta from the app?

Comment: @Louis you need to enable sites from the settings.

Comment: meeeeeeeeh, sup doc?

Answer (score 5):

## This is an example answer title

And this is a little bit of a body

- Here is a bullet
- and another

> This is a quotation

```
// WATCH OUT...
// THIS IS CODE!

nothing.selfDestruct();
```

And [this is a hyperlink](http://bit.ly/TNCQ1)

**Beware of the infinite looping**

---

*Italics*

1. here is a ordered list
2. with it's second...
3. and third partner

   Exception up = new Exception();

   throw up;

And finally:

[image: a random picture]

Comment: This is the most example post I've ever seen!

Answer (score 2):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > ## ***[do-not-press-this-button](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/do-not-press-this-button)***

Comment: I pressed it anyway! Ti-hi

Answer (score 1):

- Can

  - It

    1. Handle

       - Nested

         > elements
         >
         > ```
         >     ?
         > ```
         >
         > > > > > > > > [image]

         ```
         Perhaps.
         ```

         - ## But

           - How

             - Many

               - Levels?

                 - Maybe

                   - Here?

                     - Or

                       - Here?

                         - Or

                           - Even

                             - Here?

                               - [image]

Comment: Well, if nothing else it broke the web interface :S

Comment: where have I seen that before ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Links

- [This is a named link](http://superuser.com)
- [This is a named link - with title](http://superuser.com)

## Tags

- [i-like-turtles](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/i-like-turtles)
- [i-like-turtles](/questions/tagged/i-like-turtles) (meta)

## Spoilers

> I took the cake!

## Syntax highlighting <sup>(in theory)</sup>

```js
setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Love that spoiler!

Answer (score 0):

## Testing YouTube URL Embedding

**Regular** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Timestamped** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22

---

**Shortened** `https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Embed** `https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Embedded HTML** `<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

---

**Mobile** `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Flash Player** `https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**YouTube TV** `https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8

Answer (score -1):

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>Sorry, had to be done...</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>